# PHP strict type of variables

Tags: php

Alright so is there any way to have strict variables in PHP? Or well their types like in C#.

Example

```
class test {
      public int $myInt = 5;
      public bool $myBool = true;
      public string $myString = "This is a string";
}
```

and if so how?

Also if its possible, is there any benefit from this? Im asking since I know lots of languages use datatypes for variables and I never seen in PHP.

I have tried using this on my own localhost and did some research but I ended up with errors when I tried to execute this code

Comment: https://wshell.wordpress.com/2009/10/08/quicky-1-php-is-loosely-typed-what-does-that-meand/

Comment: You can specify types for function arguments. See http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: Dynamic typing like this is common in scripting languages. Python and Javascript are similar in not requiring you to declare variable types.

Comment: Yes i know but i prefer static variables thats why im asking